# TypeORM: helper methods on entities using data mapper pattern

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

We're building a rather large application and opted to use TypeORM's [data mapper pattern](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/active-record-data-mapper) for maintenance purposes. We are using TypeORM version `0.2.45`.

When I define a method on my entity classes, these seem to get lost when reading from the database.

**Example entity**

```js
export class Person implements IPerson {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  getFullName(title: string): string {
    return `${title}. ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}

export interface IPerson {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

**Example schema**

```js
import { EntitySchema } from 'typeorm';

export const PersonSchema = new EntitySchema<IPerson>({
  name: Person.name,
  columns: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'text',
      nullable: false,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'text',
      nullable: false,
    },
  },
});
```

**Example repository and usage**

```js
import { EntityRepository, Repository, getCustomRepository } from 'typeorm';

@EntityRepository(PersonSchema)
export class PersonRepository extends Repository<Person> {}

const personRepository = getCustomRepository(PersonRepository);

const person = await personRepository.findOne();
person.getFullName('Mr'); // Error, undefined is not a function
```

Obviously, if I just simply create a `Person`, the method exists:

```js
const person = new Person();
person.firstName = 'John';
person.lastName = 'Doe';
person.getFullName('Mr'); // Returns 'Mr. John Doe'
```

So it seems when serializing results to classes, only the fields on the schema are properly set in the class and the methods are not. So my question is twofold:

1. Is it possible to add custom methods to TypeORM entities?
2. If so, how can I achieve this using the data mapper pattern?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have an app which is using typeorm v0.3.14. I'm also using the data mapper pattern. The difference for me is that I'm not using `EntitySchema`. Rather, I'm explicitly defining each Entity class using the `@Entity` decorator. In doing so, I am able to accomplish what you're looking for - adding a custom method to my Entity class which, once queried from my repository, allows me to use that custom method.